# Dataframes not subtracting Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have two dataframes with different column names. For some reason when I subtract them, I get NaN for all rows. The error occurs at `market_4._data`

```
indicator_stats = [
        # Name, Desc, Ticker
        ['1 Normal Yield Curve', 'Z Score of 2s10s between -1 and 1', ['USGG2YR Index', 'USGG10YR Index']],
        ['2 Low Number of Large Equity Moves','',[('SPX Index','tot_return_index_gross_dvds')]],
        ['3 Normal Credit Spreads', 'Z Score of Credit Spreads between -1 and 1', ['CSI BARC Index']],
        ['4 Normal Equity to Bond Yield','', [('SPX Index','EARN_YLD'),'USGG10YR Index']]
        ]
    
result_names = ["market_1","market_2","market_3","market_4"]
        
for var, vals in zip(result_names, indicator_stats):
    name, desc, tickers = vals
    val = ct.IndicatorCalc(name=name, desc=desc, tickers = tickers)
    
    globals()[var] = val

....

    # Indicator 4. Normal Equity to Bond Yield 
    market_4._data['eq_rp'] = market_4.data['SPX Index'].asfreq('D').ffill()['SPX Index'] - market_4.data['USGG10YR Index'].asfreq('D').ffill()['USGG10YR Index']
    market_4.indicator = ct.z_score(market_4._data['eq_rp'].asfreq('M'),periods=72)
    market_4.signal = ct.z_between(market_4.indicator,-1,1)
    market.load_influence(market_4)
```

the functin `IndicatorCalc` pulls from Bloomberg, creating a dictionary of SPX's EARN_YLD and USGG10YR's PX_LAST. These successfully pull through, creating a dataframe with columns `MultiIndex([('SPX Index', 'EARN_YLD')], names=['ticker', 'field'])` and `MultiIndex([('USGG10YR Index', 'PX_LAST')], names=['ticker', 'field'])`

Sample of output:

```py
{'SPX Index': ticker     SPX Index
 field       EARN_YLD
 1954-01-29   10.2564
 1954-02-26   10.0807
 1954-03-31    9.8329
 1954-04-30    9.4607
 1954-06-30    9.0253
             ...
 2022-04-19    4.3437
 2022-04-20    4.3464
 2022-04-21    4.4115
 2022-04-22    4.5373
 2022-04-25    4.5546
 
 [9469 rows x 1 columns],
 'USGG10YR Index': ticker     USGG10YR Index
 field             PX_LAST
 1962-01-02         4.0600
 1962-01-03         4.0300
 1962-01-04         3.9900
 1962-01-05         4.0220
 1962-01-08         4.0320
                  ...
 2022-04-19         2.9361
 2022-04-20         2.8320
 2022-04-21         2.9095
 2022-04-22         2.8987
 2022-04-25         2.8140
```

Comment: can you show a sample of `market_4.data`?

Comment: Just edited the post for sample output!